# Inconsistent moderation on specific point in time?

Tags: discussion, closing, specific-question

I asked this question yesterday which was quickly closed for being "dependent on a specific point in time": 
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17560/what-is-the-most-succesful-profitable-game-that-was-based-off-a-movie

But how is that more time sensitive than this question, which remained opened and was allowed to get answered?

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12949/when-does-the-steam-christmas-sale-take-place/13000#13000

Although this sale theoretically will happen every year, it also starts on different days, and so the question will have to be updated yearly.

Comment: [That question was brought up as localized at the time](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/246217#246217). It still never got closed, though.

Comment: @Grace my chat message was a joke, obviously :) I agree that my question is borderline but I honestly don't see it as too localized, as it asks about a recurring event, and so will remain relevant in future years as well.

Comment: @Oak That was you? I know it has the same name, but the transcript has a different gravatar for you, different than even your chat profile states. I didn't bother to investigate further and figured it was the other Oak.

Comment: @Grace that's strange, not sure what happened to the gravatar, maybe I should open a bug report. But you can verify it's me by clicking on my name there.

Comment: @Oak I'll make this the last of this tangent, but it actually looks like there's some universal error going on with gravatars when it comes to different sizes. I just noticed that Kevin Y, in my envelope report, has a randomly generated gravatar despite him not changing the little bird he still has on the Users page or his profile. tzenes, too, now that I see him on the chat transcript.

Comment: @Grace no repro.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm going to give what might be an unpopular opinion:

I think part of the problem here is that this question isn't about the act of gaming. We've been a little inconsistent on where we draw the line and I think some people, myself included, feel this question is a bridge too far. This question is more about record keeping and culture than it is about playing a game. Will some people feel better about their game because of its relationship to money or movies? Sure, but it's harder to make that connection than how a question about how to near the 64th level of angry birds.

Maybe the focus of the site should be about playing games and thing which affect that, and we leave the connections to the non-gaming world to someone else

Comment: I simply wanted to know if there was ever a really successful movie based game. I *thought* the gaming stack exchange site was the correct place for that question.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I don't think the question should have been closed. The answer might change over time, but that's why can *edit* things. Games get patched all the time. Movies come out all the time. I'd be willing to bet that a hypothetical box office record being broken would happen *less* often than any particular game getting patched and invaliding existing answers.

I could see a debate over whether or not it is on topic for the site, but too localized? No way.

Comment: (Also, FWIW, since it relates to video gaming and is definitively answerable, I think it's perfectly on-topic too)

Comment: There's a subtle difference between expected maintenance for record-keeping and maintenance for accuracy. That said, I'm not entirely fond of calling it "too localized", either, because the question is actually kinda desiring to survive the test of time, not be specific to a point in time. The issue, then, is about the approach of the question - Oak's question wanted a generic answer, while Jack's question wants us to perform record-keeping. This is interesting to think about.